# Making a simple AI for a battleship program in C#

Tags: c#

I've just recently started learning to code C# to hopefully get a job someday. I'm trying to get 3 randomly generated points in a 5x5 grid. For some reason when I try to run it it just auto crashes. For testing purposes I added a Console.WriteLine and Console.ReadKey to try and see the output but it still auto closed immediately. Is there any reason why this shouldn't be working? Thanks for any help :D

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
        public void CompB()
        {
            int[] AiB = new int[6];
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int AiR = rnd.Next(0, 26);
                AiB[i] = AiR;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(AiB[0]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Comment: When your program starts, the `Main` method is run. That's it, nothing else.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think your program is correct. `for (int i = 1;` - arrays start at 0, not 1. So `AiB[1]` gets the second element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your method is not called. that is why it auto closes.
nothing is done in your program.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] AiB = new int[6];
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int AiR = rnd.Next(0, 26);
            AiB[i] = AiR;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(AiB[0]);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

now the output is:

[image]

complete code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CompB();
    }
    public static void CompB()
    {
        int[] AiB = new int[6];
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int AiR = rnd.Next(0, 26);
            AiB[i] = AiR;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(AiB[0]);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This is how i found out that the method was not used:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: It's not auto closing now so that's good. It's only outputting one number now though and it's the same one every time; 0. Also can you elaborate on how you fixed the crash issue? Like I said I'm brand new to C# and I have no clue why your fix works

Comment: Updated the answer to show how i found out that the method was not used

Comment: Ahhh I see. So for a function to happen it needs to be called in the main function? Otherwise it's just spare code?

Comment: correct!
Actually your program was workig well :) It didn't crash. It justs exited without doing anything.

Comment: @Nesox if you think this is the answer, mark it as answer :-)

Comment: Awesome :D I'm noticing an issue now though where I'm having three values displayed but the first one is always 0 and the second and third are always the same. Eg. Value of 0: 0
Value of 1: 14
Value of 2: 14

Comment: Actually that has nothing to do with your original question. Open a new topic for this issue.

Comment: Alright thank you very much for your help sir :D I can now go to bed in peace without fussing over a broken code.

Comment: Upvoted especially for the screenshots with explanation. Well constructed answer.

Answer (score 0):

As already called out above you are missing the CompB();from the main method .

One more I just looked into the for loop in line 18 it starts from in the i=1 but you are doing

System.Console.WriteLine(AiB[0]);

you should try out something like

System.Console.WriteLine(AiB[1]);

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {`enter code here`
            CompB();
        }
        public static void CompB()
        {
            int[] AiB = new int[6];
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int AiR = rnd.Next(0, 26);
                AiB[i] = AiR;
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine(AiB[1]);
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call your method CompB() from the main method. Then you have to write out all the values int the array.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CompB();
        }
        public static void CompB()
        {
            int[] AiB = new int[6];
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int AiR = rnd.Next(0, 26);
                AiB[i] = AiR;
            }
            //Write all values:
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Value of {0}: {1}", i, AiB[i]);
            }

            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```